# define php variable name with result of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to set some global variables for my site with the results of a MySQL query. It will be best to illustrate with an example I think.

```
#Query
$zone = mysql_query('SELECT zone_id, varname FROM `zone`');

if(!$zone) {
  ....
} else {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($zone)) {
    #create a variable named varname, set it to zone_id
    $tempvar = $row['zone_id'];
    $tempvar.rename_variable_to($row['varname']);

    // OR

    $$row['varname'] = row['zone_id'];
  }
}
```

I assume neither of my proposed solutions work, but thought they would help clarify the situation.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: (Also, reconsider the desire for "variable variables" - search hint, should also lead to GLOBALS - and use an appropriate collection type if possible.)

Comment: You already include the answer in your question, but apparently didn't care testing.

Comment: Whatever, why would you want to name a variable according to a value in a database? Apparently you are not using variables correctly. **Consider using an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).**

Comment: thanks for all the quick answers/pointers. I should have just sat here refreshing the page instead of tinkering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume neither of my proposed solutions work, but thought they would
>   help clarify the situation.

Bad assumption,  `$$row['varname'] = $row['zone_id'];` works

Comment: It can not work if `$row['varname']` contains invalid variable name

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your $$row['varname'] = row['zone_id']; attempt should work, only that it's $row['zone_id'] (you missed the $).

But I strongly advise you to NOT DO THIS. It allows hackers to overtake your PHP code by placing malicious stuff in the database!